# Using Mongodb Aggregation or My Own Function for the Showing of Data in Chart.js?

Tags: json, mongodb, chart.js

I'm new in this development world, I'm working with next.js.

The question I have is that I have the following information in mongodb, and I need to change it(group, add, sort) to be able to show it in chart.js.

- Initial Data

```
{
            "_id": "63fe07a24a66c599eb7ff71d",
            "date": "2023-01-30",
            "ammount": "-120",
            "company": "AMAZON.COM",
            "desciption": "Compra en establecimiento Amazon.com efectuada el 30/01/2023 Tarj # 491511******6112",
            "type": "test",
            "__v": 0
        },
```

- Expected Data

I understand that I have two options:

1. use mongodb aggregate.
2. create my own function to change the data.

However, I don't know which would be the best method to use.
If for best practices it is better to use one than the other?

use the following aggregate in mongo that brings me the data as I need it

```
const agg = [
  {
    '$match': {
      'ammount': {
        '$gt': 0
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'year': {
          '$year': '$date'
        }, 
        'month': {
          '$month': '$date'
        }
      }, 
      'total_cost_month': {
        '$sum': '$ammount'
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: as long as the mongodb can handle your handle your expecting result, use it. if not, create another function to handle the data.

Comment: If you require the initial data to compute something else, it's probably best to do it within the frontend instead.